# The file doesn't get uploaded on the server

Tags: php, file, upload

I want a user to upload his resume which gets saved to my server and send an email with the link. But for some reason the file is not getting uploaded. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
//This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it 
function findexts ($filename) 
{$filename = strtolower($filename); 
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);  
$n = count($exts)-1; 
$exts = $exts[$n]; 
return $exts;} 

//This applies the function to our file 
$ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); 

//This line assigns a random number to a variable. 
$ran = rand ();

//This takes the random number (or timestamp) you generated and adds a . on the end
$ran2 = $ran.".";

//This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into... make sure it exists!
$target_path = "/resume/";

//This combines the directory, the random file name, and the extension
$target_paths = $target_path . $ran2.$ext;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

$file_name="http://www.mydomain.com".$target_paths;

?>
```

Comment: Checked the folder permissions? What errors do you get?

Comment: No error is shown. It directly sends a mail to the email id i provided. The folder I created on the server shows empty. And what permissions are you talkin abt. I am sorry I am new to this.

Comment: The folder needs write permissions from the user the web server runs as.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a Windows (forgive me) box, file or folder permissions are the first place to look. Un*x-like systems can be (read: are) very strict.

The way I usually fix this on my dev machine, is:

- Add myself to the webservice group, making it my primary (as root: $ usermod -g webservice-group username)
- Set my user and webservice group to all files (root from project webroot: $ chown -R 755 ./*)
- Apply the 775 to all files and folders (root from project webroot: $ chmod -R 775 ./*)

This works for dev environments. I can't say I fully recommend it in a live environment. Safer in a live environment would be: folder owned by webservice-user:webservice-group (debian-based commonly: www-data:www-data) and the mod should be 755 (webservice has full access, whilst the rest can only execute and read).

Answer (score 0):

There is no validation of file type here, there is no file_exist, etc.

If you want random filenames, I would either checksum the file contents and use that as a filename, or have a loop (while file_exists=>gen_random). Though this will get exponantially slower, so you should consider using a database as a way to keep track of the files / file owners.

That beeing said, you have to check what gets uploaded, so people dont upload malicious scripts to your webpage. You should also use error handling.

If you for some reason wish to run this script - as is, you can echo out variables.
You can also do: if(move_uploaded... Else... (so you know where it fails and if it fails).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed the write permissions but still it doesn't upload the file to that folder. I have added the if statement for error handling too. And it shows that error when I tried to upload.